# Static statements inside a function

Tags: c++, static

To clarify what I mean by static statement, it is a statement that should only be executed once when the function is called, and not every time the function is called, similar to a static variable inside a function.

I know of three ways to do it, and I'd like to know which one is better for both readability, possibly performance, if there's any different and any other factors that differ.

#### First Option:

```
void f()
{
    static bool statement_done = false;
    if ( !statement_done )
    {
        do_something();
        statement_done = true;
    }
}
```

This option requires having a static bool and setting it after doing it, I would prefer it to do it another way because it can be easy to forget to set it to true afterwards, although it does say the intention of do_something() clearly, it should only be executed once

#### Second Option:

```
void f()
{
    static int _anon0 = []()
    {
        do_something();
        return 0;
    }();
}
```

This option uses an anonymous int with it's initalization being a lambda that returns an int, but also calls do_something before doing so.

#### Third Option:

```
void f()
{
    static int _anon0 = ([]{ do_something(); }(), 0);
}
```

This third one is an abuse of the comma operator, which I'm not sure works in every possible case, but on godbolt, I've seen that it generates the required assembly of calling do_something() on this example;

Is there a better option for doing something like this? And if not, which of these three should be used?

#### Motivation:

My motivation for this question was storing data in a function for later use so it doesn't have to be recalculated every time, more specifically a draw function of a circle, I wanted to store all of the sine and cosine calls since they are quite expensive and they're always the same every time, so I did something like this:

```
void Circle::draw()
{
    static vector2 data[30];
    static int a = [](vector2(&data)[30])
    {
        for (size_t n=0; n<30; n++)
        {
            data[n][0] = std::cos(2*pi * n / 30.0f);
            data[n][1] = std::sin(2*pi * n / 30.0f);
        }
        
        return 0;
    }(data);
    
    draw(...); // Draws using data
}
```

I wasn't able to capture data in the lambda because the compiler told me it was an error to capture variables with storage class of static, which somewhat makes sense.

Comment: Why not `static sometype t = somefunc();`?

Comment: Checkout [C++ Weekly - Ep 2 Cost of Using Statics](https://youtu.be/B3WWsKFePiM)

Comment: @BoR I'm too lazy to watch a youtube video, but there really isn't much of a cost here. Maybe a single cache miss to access `static vector2 data[30];` from `draw(...); // Draws using data`. You can't really do any better performance wise if that data is the same for every `Circle` and will never change.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That's essentially the same as the lambda, except I don't have to create another function and can do it inline.

Comment: @BoR So does this mean the first method would be better due to not generating all of that assembly boilerplate?

Comment: I've checked the duplicate and std::call_once seems to fit what I need to do perfectly, since it can take a lambda and so populate the vector array.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Option one is good in a single threaded environment. But in a multithreaded environment it's easy to have multiple calls to `do_something()`. If stuck on C++98 then using the comma trick as in `static bool const statement_done = (do_something(), true);` with generate the same code as in option two and three.